# how to fix broken grub after already having tried to repair it?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I recently added another partition to my hardrive where ubuntu was installed to and afterwards when I booted ubuntu I got sent to the grub rescue> terminal. The fix for that was that I had to reinstall grub on the correct partition for ubuntu to boot again. So I followed all the instructions from ubuntu to fix it from the live cd here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202 .

After I was done doing that I rebooted and the grub> terminal is now there. I would usually see a list to choose from with my os but Im guessing I have to update grub when I reboot or load the menu list. The problem is I did a lot of research to figure out how to boot from grub> but I cannot find a way to do so.

It is not easy finding a tutorial for doing so and I am completley stuck. I would like to know an easy way to boot into my ubuntu from grub and making the booting as it was before I made the partition. Please any help would be greatly appreciated for I need to get on my ubuntu to start doing some work...

Comment: Post the output of boot_info_script please... http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a

```
sudo update-grub
```

after you booted from the live-cd?

If it doesn't work you should give [SuperGrubDisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) a try.
 With SuperGrubDisk you can choose between booting into your ubuntu, if possible, or repairing GRUB2.

Comment: Is there a difference with installing grub 1 or grub 2 I am sure I had grub 2 previously but the link I posted said that was the fix for the grub 2 but when I boot it says the grub terminal with version like 1.98 so do I have to do an update or should I just install grub 2 if there is a different way to do it?

Comment: Grub 1.98 is Grub 2. The original Grub got as far as .97 then the thing was re-written becoming 1.98 and 1.99 and some day 2, I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing recently, until I realized that for my 64-bit Ubuntu installation I needed to use the 64-bit Ubuntu LiveCD.  I followed these instructions which I found in another thread:

Just insert live cd [64-bit, in my case] and began ubuntu with livecd. Then goto

Applications->Accessories->Terminal then type sudo fdisk -l and find ubuntu installed partition.

then type the following in terminal

sudo mkdir /media/sdax ( here x is ubuntu installed partition number)

sudo mount /dev/sdax /media/sdax

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/sdax /dev/sda

then restart your system without live cd and type the following in terminal

sudo update-grub

(This is from [grub-install from live CD (urgent)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48390/grub-install-from-live-cd-urgent)[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48390/grub-install-from-live-cd-urgent) and was given by Arulmozhir.)