# Lubuntu 20.04 does not boot from HDD following install from USB (Toshiba L350 laptop)

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, lubuntu, mbr

For context, my laptop was a dual boot between windows 7 (not used in over 3 years) an Lubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04 last year).
I created a bootable USB from the ISO and set to install.
Upon reboot, I realized that I needed the USB key to boot to the installed version.
I recreated an installation USB and ran the install again.
That's when I saw that /dev/sda (the USB) was the default storage device and boot loader location.
So the next around I selected /dev/sdb, but now I get an error while creating a new partition (type:msdos) on sdb.
I can get around that error by selecting the manual partitioning option, so that the installation actually finishes but it never boots off the disk.
Although I've been using Lubuntu for several years, I am far from a power user, so parameters like the mount point and flags are a little out of my league.
If anyone has any idea what may be going on here, I would appreciate a little clarification.
THanks

======UPDATE=================
I wish I could say a proper solution was found, though not for lack of looking, but my problem is now resolved. So I'll enumerate what I tried, none of which resulted in my system finding grub on boot (or booting at all)

As a quick reminderb to what happened, I went from a dual boot Windows 7 /Lubuntu 18.04 to a lone installation of Lubuntu 20.04. On reboot, not bootabale device was found.

Here is what I tried:

1. boot-repair
   a. Default
   b. advanced, changing boot device to sdb as my liveUSB was taking sda
   c. restore MBR
2. `Grub-install /dev/sdb` + `update-grub`
3. Boot from LiveMedia, mount my linux partition (/dev/sdb), `chroot` to /mnt and ruuning `grub-install /dev/sdb` from there (as per [askubuntu.com/questions/48390/grub-install-from-live-cd-urgent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48390/grub-install-from-live-cd-urgent))
4. Boot from bootable grub2 usb, successfully booting my install and running `grub-install /dev/sda` (yes my install was back on sda during that scenario)
5. Using  `grub rescue` (https://christitus.com/grub-rescue/#fix-grub-permanently )

In the end,I picked up an old Windows XP CD, installed that on a reformatted NTFS drive, then ran the same installation USB, this time installing alongside XP (reducing the XP partition to its minimum 3GB - it doesn't matter, I'll never use it). The laptop now boots properly to grub2 and allows me to select my lubuntu installation. I think, 3GB of disk space is a small proce to pay for the amount of time I spent on this problem

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, especially a patient @guiverc.

Comment: So clearly you didn't do the manual partitioning right. The "Erase Disk" option would show up normally but my guess is you have something automounted, most likely swap from the old install. A `sudo swapoff -a` before install should fix it up. BTW it's in the manual: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html#setting-up-partitions

Comment: I don't know if you read release notes, but I suspect so given your description reads like you used one of the listed work-arounds (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/).. The installer lets you pick which device the bootloader is written to (seen at the top of the screen in the picture on the manual page @wxl used).  If you can boot your system, you can also use `sudo grub-install /dev/*sdx*` (where *sdx* will be replaced by whichever device your system boots from & you want to write to; but note it's more complicated if using live media; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Comment: Thanks wxl and guiverc. Honestly, I thought swapoff did not apply since I was wiping the entire disc, but rereading that paragraph in the manual, I really thought that was it. But I just tried it and get the same result.

Comment: guiverc, I'm not sure I follow your grub recommendation, as it it starts with "if you can boot your system", and the answer to that is "no". The only way I can boot into anything if to use the iso on usb and boot into installation mode. At that point, I'm not sure if using grub-install would amount to anything.  Again apologies for any comments which prompts you to say " this guy doesn't know what he's doing". I do admit I'm swimming in a dark ocean at the moment. Thanks again!\

Comment: No my comment won't have been very newbie helpful.. and details were there if you search for `chroot` doing it from a *live* or install media in the URL I provided... (easy for me as I know to search for `chroot`). I know a lot of users like boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) though answers here may help too, eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/48390/grub-install-from-live-cd-urgent (maybe read in conjunction with official link from my prior comment.. ie. an end-users understanding from details in my prior *official* grub2 doco link for their machine..)

Comment: @guiverc, here is how the story progressed today. Boot-repair did not work even restoring MBR. Nor did `grub-install` whilst on my live install. The closest to sucess was through a grub2 bootable usb, when I got the grub rescue.  I was able to `set root=(hd1,msdos1)` then `set prefix=(hd1,msdos1)/boot/grub`. Finally `instmod normal` and `normal` allowed me to boot from my disk, but once booted in, `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sda` still did not accomplish the task, as the laptop still fails to boot properly. Perhaps this new information may help.

Comment: I can't help with boot-repeat. The `grub-install` needs to be done after you've switched the 'root' device (`chroot`) from the *live* media to your installed system, otherwise the grub-install will point to the live media itself (meaning it'll only work when live media is installed).  If you get error messages those are required for us to help (if no error messages existed in `sudo grub-install` I'd expect it relates to issues in changing root device required before-hand. Yes your getting it to boot is helpful, please paste any messages when you run the `grub-install /dev/sda` in your question

Comment: `grub-install`  reports no error so, I'll have to ramp up my understanding of root switching (`chmod`). I was hopeful because the live media is in no way involved when I boot through grub rescue. Looks like a few more hours of fun! Thanks again!

Comment: I tried  the `chroot` method, still no dice, but no errors. I must be wrong about this but I get the feeling that since my live media occupies sda, my  permanent linux install is on sdb (and so I have to run `grub-install /dev/sdb` after`chroot`), when I reboot without the usb, there is no mbr on sda so grub is not found.  But I might be way off. If I find my old windows 7 installer, I may reinstall that and try to again run with a side by side installation even though I won't use windows 7. Heck, at least that worked before.