# How to format disk without installing system?

Tags: installation, 10.04, grub2, partitioning

I want to move system to another machine. I have full backup in .tar.gz file as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR). Now I need to partition hard drive, install grub and unpack archive. How to do that? When I tried to use Live CD it started installing system immediately after partitioning and I need clean partition to unpack my archive to.

Comment: Did you use gparted to partion the disk? I never experienced what you described, when using gparted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, for instance, with the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

> GParted Live is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers.
>   It enables you to use all the features of the latest versions of the GParted application.
>
> GParted Live can be installed on CD, USB, PXE server, and Hard Disk then run on an x86 machine.
>
> **Installation Instructions**
>
> To install GParted Live on CD, [download](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) the .iso file and burn it as an image to a CD.
>
> **Accounts in GParted live**
>
> GParted live is based on Debian live, and the default account is "user", with password "live". There is no root password, so if you need root privileges, login as "user", then run "sudo" to get root priviliges.

But  if you already have a Ubuntu Live CD you can run GParted or Disc Utility and from there GParted after choosing the option `Try Ubuntu` instead of `Install Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the installer then.  Use the Disk Utility or gparted to partition and format the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use live and GParted or fdisk  Not the installer auto-config partitioner if you want to do this.  You can let the auto-partitioner do it's thing and kill the installer, but then you have to install grub from rescue/live.

All the parts of this question have been asked before:
[How do I partition my drive from live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89988/is-it-possible-to-use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-and-run-gparted-to-partition-a-my-hdd-i)
How to restore is covered on the page you cited.  You need to do the restore BEFORE you do the grub reinstall.
[How do I reinstall grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32257/how-to-fix-broken-grub-after-already-having-tried-to-repair-it)